# "We can't save the customer" error after Migration - Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, customer, controllers

I have migrated store from Magento 1.7.0.2 to Magento 2.3.
When i Create the customer it shows me error "**We can't save the customer.**"

I have checked log file and i can see log, "Class Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Label does not exist".
I have checked this path, and Label.php does not exist.
Can you guys please help me?!!

Is there any issue related to customer attribute?
How can i debug and fix this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes,I am not sure about it. but it is clear that the issue is happening for some custom attribute.

Some of the attribute's `frontend_input` field value is `label` and that is wrong.magento does not have this type of `frontend_input` type field.

So, you have to find that attribute, first goto database  and then `eav_attribute` goto run below code:

> SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` where frontend_input = 'label'

You **have to delete those attributes** .But its means you willbe lost  value of this field of catalog product/category/customer entity

Comment: Yes,You are right.There was one customer attribute in eav_attribute table which has 'label' as input type.I have changed it to 'text' from 'label' and it is working fine for me now.Thanks !!!

Comment: @amitbera, i am facing the same issue, i followed your answer but i didn't find any frontend_input 'label' value in the database table "eav_attribute". how do i proceed further could you please provide any alternative ways to achieve this? we have upgrade M2.2.3 CE to 2.3.1 CE recently. first time throws error (but customer record is saving) next time when we try with the same details it saying customer already existed. please help me

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be resolved by put session to 'db' instead of 'files'

Please find **app/etc/env.php** and change "**'session_save' => array('save' => 'files')**" to "**session_save' => array('save' => 'db')**" . This is Mangeto 2 known bug.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But it was solved by @Amit Bera 's answer.Thanks again.

Comment: the above one is not working for me.